# Ubuntu - ls -Z only shows question marks and file names

Tags: ubuntu, ls, selinux

When I'm using `ls -Z /etc` I only get question marks and filenames. I don't get anything about the security context. Does anyone know anything about this?

[image: ls -z output]

Comment: Are you sure the files _have_ a security context set at all?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running a regular installation of Ubuntu <s>(judging from the colors of your terminal)</s>. SELinux, which gives a security context ([amongst others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux)) is not enabled in Ubuntu by default, and I actually doubt pretty much that you want to enable it at all.

Ubuntu by default uses [AppArmor](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/security-apparmor), which is an alternative to SELinux. However, AppArmor works differently and does not collaborate with `ls -Z`. SELinux support in Ubuntu is considered experimental, and if you really want to run SELinux, you will be better off with a RedHat based distro.

If you are unsure whether your system actually has SELinux enabled, try typing `sudo sestatus`. Most likely, you will get `sudo: sestatus: command not found`. What you *should* see in Ubuntu is the output of `sudo aa-status` (a similar command from AppArmor).

[Here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/apparmor-vs-selinux) is a nice comparison between AppArmor and SELinux.